# Команда FFmpeg в BAT файле

Tags: cmd, bat, ffmpeg

Всем привет.
Есть команда FFmpeg, которая берет источник звука и записывает его на фрагменты по минуте. Запуская ее в CMD всё работает хорошо:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Лин. вход (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
-ac 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 120k -f segment -segment_time 60
-segment_format mp3 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1
d:\REC\ffmpeg\%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp3
```

Решил сделать из нее BAT-файл. Audio вход заменил на латиницу (в CMD работает) и дату файла переделал под формат BAT-файла:

```
echo off
title REC
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{D1A89BF0-6B37-475D}"
-ac 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 120k -f segment -segment_time 60
-segment_format mp3 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1
d:\REC\ffmpeg\%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.mp3"
```

Но теперь при запуске BAT-файла не сохраняются сегменты по 1 минуте. Запись идет бесконечно, но если ее остановить, то создастся файл с именем времени когда был запущен BAT-файл, а внутри звук от последней минуты. Ощущение, что FFmpeg продолжает делить поток на минуты, но не может сохранить это в файлы.
Как сделать так, чтоб FFmpeg запускаясь из BAT-файла продолжал создавать файлы по одной минуте?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"
chcp 1251 > nul
cmd /c "ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Лин. вход (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
-ac 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 120k -f segment -segment_time 60
-segment_format mp3 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1
d:\REC\ffmpeg\%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp3"
```

Сохранить файл нужно в кодировке Windows-1251.

Comment: Сохранил в кодировке Windows-1251. Ситуация аналогичная. Запись идёт, но файлы по 1 минуте не создаются.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался я. Запускаю скрипт в powershell и всё выполняется как надо.